# BadImgeFormatException when trying to run application after reinstalling Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, c++, dll, clr

I hope this question will not be regarded as a duplicate as I know there are many similar questions on stackoverflow. I should know. I already read most of them. So bear with me...

I am writing a C# application that relies on the OpenCV libraries to function. The OpenCV libraries are written in c++ code and to use them in c#, I wrote 2 libraries: a static library containing the methods I want from OpenCV; a CLR DLL that acts like a bridge between the static lib and the C# project.

What perplexes me is the fact that everything worked fine until I reinstalled Windows 8.1 due to a virus. Before the reinstall, the app compiled and ran just like intended. After the reinstall, the very same project throws a "BadImageFormatException" when trying to debug:

```
namespace G19_GUI
{
   static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new GUI.GUI()); //this is the line producing the exception
        }
    }
}
```

```
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'clrLib, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

I know the most common cause for this exception is that the application is trying to load a 32bit library into a 64bit compiled application or vice-versa. As such, I verified that the OpenCV libraries I am trying to use are destined for use in a 32bit application and indeed they are. I tried switching to the 64bit dlls, action that produced 39 errors of type "LINK2028: unresolved token".

Keep in mind that the project itself did not change at all between the 2 installations of Windows. I used the same property sheet and the same OpenCV libraries. Everything was kept on an external drive, which was unplugged at the time I foolishly double clicked the virus executable, and backed up on DropBox, the only thing I had to do after reinstalling Windows was to reset the path and OpenCV environment variables, which I did using a .bat file, the same .bat file used to set those very same variables in the first install of Windows. Therefore, I highly doubt the possibility of the virus messing with my project files. Even so, I double-checked everything and couldn't find anything wrong.

I proceeded to documenting the exception online. As a result, I ended up trying every possible  combination of configuration builds and target platforms I dared have the patience to try for all of the 3 projects I had in my solution.

Indeed, trying to build and compile for a 64bit machine removed the exception but another DLL my C# project depended on was destined for 32bit use and when trying to load that DLL, the very same exception popped up (which was expected). Unfortunately, the DLL did not come with a 32bit version or with a source code to try and build my own 64bit version of said DLL.

Thus, I am forced to build my application either for both target platforms (any cpu, mixed platform, whatever) or only for 32bit. Which, of course, produces the exception at start-up.

I know all my DLLs are made for 32bit use. For the life of me, I cannot figure out what the problem is, nor why this problem did not exist before I reinstalled the os.

Below is the code of my clrLib dll:

```
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "clrLib.h"
#include <vector>

namespace clrLib
{
    public ref class mapper
    {
private:
    static openCVProc * myProc;
public:
    static mapper(void)
    {
        myProc = new openCVProc();
    }

    char * mapStringToChar(String ^ path)
    {
        return (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(path);
    }

    array<int>^ getRGBfromHSV(int h, int s, int v)
    {
        array<int>^ values = gcnew array<int>(3);
        std::vector<int> myVals = myProc->hsv2rgb(h, s, v);
        values[0] = myVals[0];
        values[1] = myVals[1];
        values[2] = myVals[2];

        return values;
    }

    array<int>^ getHSV(String^ src)
    {
        array<int>^ vals = gcnew array<int>(3);

        vals[0] = (myProc->getHSV(mapper::mapStringToChar(src)))[0];
        vals[1] = (myProc->getHSV(mapper::mapStringToChar(src)))[1];
        vals[2] = (myProc->getHSV(mapper::mapStringToChar(src)))[2];
        return vals;
    }

    void openCam()
    {
        myProc->startCam();
    }

    void closeCam()
    {
        myProc->stopCam();
    }

    int^ getBrightness()
    {
        int^ b;
        b = myProc->getB();
        return b;
    }

    bool^ camState()
    {
        return myProc->camState();
    }

    array<Byte>^ mapper::getFrameData()
    {
        cv::Mat f = myProc->getFrame();
        int width = f.cols;
        int height = f.rows;

        array<Byte>^ bitmapData = gcnew array<Byte>(width*height * 3);
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                bitmapData[c] = f.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
                bitmapData[c + 1] = f.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
                bitmapData[c + 2] = f.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[2];
                c += 3;
            }
        }

        return bitmapData;

    }

    Size^ mapper::getFrameSize()
    {
        std::vector<int> size = myProc->getFrameSize();
        Size^ frameSize = gcnew Size(size[0], size[1]);
        return frameSize;
    }
};
```

}

The other 2 libraries are a bit lengthy, but I will include them if need be.

Thank you for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: You never mentioned the *one* setting that matters.  So it is probably wrong.  Right-click your Winforms project, Properties, Compile tab, change the Platform target setting to x86.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: There is no compile tab. The only tab that seems relevant is the build tab. As I have said before and as can be seen in this [image](http://i.imgur.com/hsdp4vP.png)  (correct me if this is not the correct properties window) i already tried setting the target platform and the config to x86

Comment: Yes, that one.  Next thing to do is run SysInternals' Process Monitor, you can see exactly what DLLs your program loads.  The bad one will be near the end of the trace.  Double-check its bitness with dumpbin.exe /headers.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it now and i'll get back to you once I tried it. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not even know of the existence of SysInternals prior to posting this question so please advise if my usage was correct. I have included screenshots of the [Processor Monitor](http://i.imgur.com/YFEwCMa.png) window as well as the [Processor Explorer](http://i.imgur.com/HrXoSpm.png) and the dumpbin result, both of which point to the ntdll.dll near the end of the process. As you can see in the image, the dll is clearly a 64bit image. After researching a bit online, I found it is related to nvidia drivers perhap? I clean reinstalled the drivers and the problem persists.

Comment: Also, I tried removing the dll but apparently only "TrustedInstaller" has rights to modify the file, even changing the file's owner to my Windows user (or administrator), I still seem to be unable to remove it. I have no idea why it is trying to load that dll ...

Comment: No, that's not it.  Don't mess with it, your program actually loads c:\windows\syswow64\ntdll.dll.  You are supposed to look towards the end of the trace, not the start.  If you need somebody else to look at the ProcMon trace then save it and make it available at a file sharing service.

Comment: I saved it and it can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vei5pj4bazj79e9/GUI.PML?dl=0).

Comment: You cut off the trace too soon.  But the basic problem is clear, you are running as a 64-bit process.  Back to my first comment.  Maybe the strange build folder ("myDebug") has something to do with it as well, I can't tell if you are running the Release build and forgot to change the Platform target setting.

Comment: I double checked everything and both libraries are set to debug x86 and the app itself is also set to debug win32. The "myDebug" folder is used as the output/build path for all three projects. It's a requirement made by my team leader that I output everything into one folder. However, I did notice something was off. The "last modified date" on the static lib files were indicating that they have not been modified since before I reinstalled the os. For some reason I have not figure out yet, visual studio does not rebuild that static lib, whatever the build or target platform settings...